# Reading data from ArduPilot's telemetry port using cable

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, telemetry

Good day.

I need to read telemetry from ArduPilotMega's telemetry port
using SERIAL-USB converter and usb cable.

How can i to do it?

[image]

I try to use python:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=57600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

line = []

while True:
    for c in ser.read():
        line.append(c)
        if c == '\n':
            print line
            line = []
```

Result looks like this:

> connected to: /dev/ttyUSB0
> ['\x1c', '\x01', '\x1e', 'V', '\x00',
> '\x8c', '=', '\xe2', '\xbc', 'v', '\xc0', '\xf6', '8', ',', '\xba',
> 'E', '8', '%', '\x14', '\x01', 'J', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00',
> 'Q', '\xc0', 'c', '>', '\x00', '\x00', '\xc2', '\x1a', '\x01', '\x1b',
> '\x12', '"', '\x00', '\x00', '\xff', '\xff', '\xfc', '\x00', '\x00',
> '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xa1', '\x0e', '\x01', '\x1d', 'V',
> '\x00', '\xdb', 'D', 'f', '>', '\r', '\xec', '\x1f', '\x01', '\x01',
> '\xfc', '\x00', '\xfc', '\x00', '\xfc', '\x00', '\x01', '\x00',
> '\xff', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\xed',
> '\xfe', '\xa4', '\x01', '\xf6', '.',  ....

How can i to decode it?

Is it correct way?

Thank you!

Comment: My solution: using a usb port instad of telem-port and this [python example](https://github.com/marhar/eastbay-mavlink/tree/master/demos)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're reading hexadecimal characters and then concatenating them. Try this instead:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=57600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=0)

print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)

while True:
    print ser.readline()
```